# How to create dynamic folder and subfolder to insert exported files into?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my actual project, my boss asked me to export data from database to csv flat files.

So, as I don't know .net code, I use SSIS File System task and ForEach Loop Container.

I built a package which:

1. Select data filtered by year, month and region
2. Create differents folder to archive files exported like this:

> A- Year\MONTH\REGION\ .csvfiles

One difficulty that I have is to create folder and sub folder only if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm lazy, I'd drop a Script Task in the Foreach Loop Container and make use of the [System.IO.Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx). Specifically, I'd use [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) and [CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)

Comment: Thank U billinkc for your answer.So

Comment: Thank U billinkc for your answer.So could U help me more. I am not familiar with .Net code. Could U give me an example in details  of using of your solution ? Or Do U think if it is possible to do that with SSIS file system task and foreach loop container ? Thank U